# GCP FCM : Are device registration tokens required for in app notifications?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a project where I have to send in app notifications to selected users (identified by the userId with which they logged in) using GCP's FCM. Do we need to register device tokens for this? Or how else do we ensure the notification reaches only those particular users? Is there any document which specifies this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - In order to receive notifications the software must be installed on a device and your backend needs to store the notification token for each device that is currently used by that user. (also remember that these token can be refreshed sometimes).

Sending a notification to a specific device/user requires this.

Comment: So when the user logs in, I need to create a token for that device, and save it in the backend/database? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yep - if you want to send specific messages to specific devices from the backend then that's what you do.  If you want to send the same message to lots of people you should look at FCM topics or FCM device groups.